# Creating new elements with jQuery using $(html, props) and attaching .data

Tags: jquery

I am creating a list item on the fly using the object notation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) and I would like to be able to add a jQuery `.data()` (http://api.jquery.com/data/) to it.

I have the current code:

```
$('<li>', {
        id: 'filter',
        text: 'Data Filter 1',
        click: function() {
            filter['jQuery_object'] = $(this);
            filters_display.trigger('remove', filter);
        }
    }).appendTo($(this));
```

And I have tried this:

```
$('<li>', {
        id: 'filter',
        text: 'Data Filter 1',
        load: function() {
            $(this).data('filter', filter);
        },
        click: function() {
            filter['jQuery_object'] = $(this);
            filters_display.trigger('remove', filter);
        }
    }).appendTo($(this));
```

But the `.load()` event does not seem to be triggered when the `<li>` is appended to the DOM. Is there a way to accomplish this without selecting the new `<li>` via it's id?

I envisaged it working something like this by returning an array of objects:

```
$('<li>', {
        id: 'filter',
        text: 'Data Filter 1',
        data: function() {
            return [{ key: 'filter', value: filter }]
        }
        click: function() {
            filter['jQuery_object'] = $(this);
            filters_display.trigger('remove', filter);
        }
    }).appendTo($(this));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var div = $("<div></div>", {
    data: {
        foo: "bar"
    }
});

alert( div.data("foo") ); // => bar
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add `.data('filter', filter)` to your chain ...

```
$('<li>', {
        id: 'filter',
        text: 'Data Filter 1',
        click: function() {
            filter['jQuery_object'] = $(this);
            filters_display.trigger('remove', filter);
        }
    }).appendTo($(this)).data('filter', filter);
```

Comment: That will attach the data to $(this) and not the li won't it?

Comment: @Treffynnon -- nope, `appendTo()` will still return the newly created `<li>` -- see: http://jsfiddle.net/wrwfG/

Answer (score 0):

I asked in the jQuery IRC channel and it is as simple as:

```
var div = $("<div></div>", {
    data: {
        foo: "bar"
    }
});

alert( div.data("foo") );
```

Answer from the jQuery IRC channel: http://jsfiddle.net/ehynds/3kw3v/

Comment: The accepted answer is from the same person who helped in the IRC channel.